# ngx-rocket backend proxy not working

Tags: angular, angular6

I have use the generator-ngx-rocket to setup an default ngx-rocket app. Now I want to change the proxy config so that calls to `/api` will be redirected to `http://localhost:8080/api` (which is my backend spring-boot app) instead of `http://localhost:4200/api` which is my ng dev server.

I have changed the following in the proxy.conf.js:

```
const proxyConfig = [
  {
    context: '/api',
    pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false
  }
];
```

and when I make an http request like `this.httpClient.get<any[]>('/companies');` I get an error telling me that I requested `http://localhost:4200/api/companies`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this problem, and I'm just a newbie, so take what I'm going to say with a grain of salt.

You have to understand what is happening. That proxy is a backend proxy, which helps in redirecting different requests to different endpoints.

Even if you see localhost:4200, internally it's being redirected. The results are shown on the console where you launched the npm start command. You'll see it's rewriting from localhost:4200 to localhost:8080.

I don't fully understand the concept of context, but if you read your configuration, you are stating the requests should erase the /api prefix (the pathRewrite option). Toy with that, see if you can make it work. My proxy.conf.js looks like yours, but I set my context to '/' so every request gets proxied, and no pathRewrite at all.

edit: also remember you set your serverUrl in the environment.ts and environment.prod.ts